# Evenly spacing several rows of an arbitrary number of elements using NSLayoutConstraints

Tags: ios, objective-c, autolayout, nslayoutconstraint

I have a question about using layout constraints for the following scenario. Everything is in code (no nibs or storyboards). I want to create a view that contains an arbitrary number of rows of items. Each row contains an arbitrary number of subviews.

To create this view, I want to pass in an array that is two levels deep. The first level array contains each row. The second level array contains the elements in each row. So, for example, this might look like this:

`NSArray *elements = @[@[subview1, subview2, subview3], @[subview4], @[subview5, subview6]]`

In this array, there would be 3 rows:

1) Row 1: subview1, subview2, subview3
2) Row 2: subview4
3) Row 3: subview5, subview6

I want these elements to be formatted as:

-The rows should all be the full width of their parent view (for this we can assume it's the size of the screen)
-Each of the elements in a row should be the same width and have the same amount of space between them (say if there are 4 elements, the space between 1&2 and 2&3 could be 10pt)
-Each of the rows should have the same amount of vertical space between them (e.g. 10pt vertical space between each row)

In the scenario above, row 1 would have 3 subviews with equal width equally spaced apart, row 2 would have 1 subview which takes up the full width of the row, and row 3 would have 2 subviews that have equal width and would be equally spaced apart.

So, the question is, how do I do this?!

I've been working on this for awhile and my understanding doesn't seem to be getting any better. Help would be appreciated!

Comment: Do you determine the 10 pt spacing, or do you expect autolayout to choose the spacing?  If you expect autolayout to choose the spacing, how do you want it to choose?

Comment: @robmayoff I would input the amount of spacing I wanted -- it wouldn't be calculated by autolayouts.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Something like this should work I think. I tried to make in general, so it should work for different number of rows and elements per row.

```
#define subviewHeight 44
#define spaceFromTop 10
#define spaceFromSide 10
#define subviewVerticalSpacing 10
#define subviewHorizontalSpacing 10

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];

    UIButton *subview1 = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    [subview1 setTitle:@"View 1" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    UIButton *subview2 = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    [subview2 setTitle:@"View 2" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    UIButton *subview3 = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    [subview3 setTitle:@"View 3" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    UIButton *subview4 = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    [subview4 setTitle:@"View 4" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    UIButton *subview5 = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    [subview5 setTitle:@"View 5" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    UIButton *subview6 = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    [subview6 setTitle:@"View 6" forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    NSArray *arrayOfSubviews = @[@[subview1, subview2, subview3], @[subview4], @[subview5, subview6]];

    [self addSubviewsWithConstraints:arrayOfSubviews];

}

-(void)addSubviewsWithConstraints:(NSArray *) arrayOfArrays {
    NSMutableArray *arrayOfViewsDicts = [NSMutableArray array]; // make the views dictionaries needed for the views parameter of constraintsWithVisualFormat:options:metrics:views:. One for each row.

    for (NSArray *array in arrayOfArrays) {
        NSMutableDictionary *dict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
        for (int i = 0; i < array.count; i++) {
            [dict setObject:array[i] forKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"view%d",i]];
        }
        [arrayOfViewsDicts addObject:dict];
    }

    for (int i=0; i<arrayOfArrays.count; i++) {
        NSString *formatString = [self makeConstraintsForRowOfSubviews:arrayOfArrays[i] withViewsDict:arrayOfViewsDicts[i]]; // Make the format string for a row of subviews

        for (id subview in arrayOfArrays[i]) {
            [subview setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];
            [self.view addSubview:subview];
            NSLayoutConstraint *heightCon = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:subview attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight relatedBy:0 toItem:nil attribute:NSLayoutAttributeNotAnAttribute multiplier:1 constant:subviewHeight];
            [subview addConstraint:heightCon];

            NSLayoutConstraint *verticalCon = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:subview attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop relatedBy:0 toItem:self.view attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop multiplier:1 constant:spaceFromTop + ((subviewHeight + subviewVerticalSpacing)*i)];
            [self.view addConstraint:verticalCon];
        }
        NSArray *cons = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:formatString options:NSLayoutFormatAlignAllBottom metrics:nil views:arrayOfViewsDicts[i]];

        [self.view addConstraints:cons];
    }
}


-(NSString *) makeConstraintsForRowOfSubviews:(NSArray *) arrayOfSubviews withViewsDict:(NSDictionary *) viewsDict {
    NSMutableString *formatString = [NSMutableString string];

    for (int i = 0; i<arrayOfSubviews.count; i++) {
        if (i == 0) {
            [formatString appendFormat:@"|-%d-[%@]",spaceFromSide,[viewsDict allKeysForObject:arrayOfSubviews[i]][0]];
        }else{
            [formatString appendFormat:@"-%d-[%@(==view0)]",subviewHorizontalSpacing,[viewsDict allKeysForObject:arrayOfSubviews[i]][0]];
        }
    }

    [formatString appendFormat:@"-%d-|",spaceFromSide];
    return formatString;
}
```

This code produced this result:

[image]

Comment: Very helpful. Thanks @rdelmar! Clever the way you constructed the VFL format strings.

Answer (score 0):

You *could* do this with autolayout, but I think your code would actually be easier to understand if you just used a `UICollectionView` with your own custom `UICollectionViewLayout` subclass.

If you really want to do it with autolayout, I think you should make your view hierarchy match your array hierarchy, by introducing a middle level of “row” views:

```
gridView
├─ rowView0
│  ├─ subview1
│  ├─ subview2
│  └─ subview3
├─ rowView1
│  └─ subview4
└─ rowView2
   ├─ subview5
   └─ subview6
```

Now you can set constraints on the rows like this:

```
// These constraints force the rows to collectively fill gridView:
rowView0.top = gridView.top
rowView1.top = rowView0.bottom + 10
rowView2.top = rowView1.bottom + 10
gridView.bottom = rowView2.bottom

// These constraints force the rows to have equal heights:
rowView1.height = rowView0.height
rowView2.height = rowView0.height

// These constraints force the rows to each be the width of gridView:
rowView0.leading = gridView.leading
rowView0.trailing = gridView.trailing
rowView1.leading = gridView.leading
rowView1.trailing = gridView.trailing
rowView2.leading = gridView.leading
rowView2.trailing = gridView.trailing
```

Those constraints should be necessary (that is, not overconstrained) and sufficient (that is, not ambiguous).

Then you can apply the same constraint scheme to each row, with the X and Y axes swapped.  For example, you would use these constraints in row 0:

```
// These constraints collectively force the cells to fill rowView0:
subview1.leading = rowView0.leading
subview2.leading = subview1.trailing + 10
subview3.leading = subview2.trailing + 10
rowView0.trailing = subview3.trailing

// These constraints force the cells to have equal widths:
subview2.width = subview1.width
subview3.width = subview1.width

// These constraints force the cells to each be the height of rowView0:
subview1.height = rowView0.height
subview2.height = rowView0.height
subview3.height = rowView0.height
```

Comment: Hey Rob -- thanks for the feedback here. Re: UICollectionView, that would make sense in many cases but the case I'm using here is for putting several rows of buttons in the header or footer of a UITableView (an analogy would be the iOS contacts).

Comment: For your answer, this would certainly work if the number of rows and the number of elements in each row were consistent. Unfortunately, I'm trying to architect this so that I could pass an array with an arbitrary number of rows which each had an arbitrary number of elements. I think what I need to do is create a UIView for each row, and then iterate through the row's elements and create the appropriate NSLayoutAttributeTrailing constraint (I might have to calculate the width prior to that). Then, I think I need to iterate through each row, add each to the final UIView, and

Comment: add a new constraint for each row view which provides the appropriate NSLayoutAttributeTop/Bottom. It sounds reasonable conceptually, but I'm having trouble implementing it :(